# Android: Sort attachments sent by mail

Tags: android, sorting, email, share, email-attachments

This is a silly and not important subject, but nothing to lose on asking.

My app has a "Share App" feature in main menu which sends a promotion email with text and a set of app screenshots, and in the end it calls the following method:

```
public static void shareFile(ArrayList<Uri> uris, String fileType)
{
    try{
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        share.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        share.setType(fileType);
        String strSubject = TMLocale.getStringResourceByName("mainmenu_sharethisapp_subject");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, strSubject);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, TMLocale.getStringResourceByName("mainmenu_sharethisapp_recommendtext"));

        share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        activity.get().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, TMLocale.getStringResourceByName("mainmenu_sharethisapp_shareapptitle")));
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(activity.get(), String.valueOf(ex.getMessage()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is working great, but what you receive -for example by mail- is an unordered set of attachments, I mean, the attachments order does not correspond to the `ArrayList<Uri>` order.

I'd like the attachments to be ordered as the ArrayList is, so who receives the email can see how the app works following the attachments (from Gmail -for example- and without downloading them) in a "readable"/"understandable" way, like following the same work sequence a user would follow using the app.

I have made several tests just to confirm attachments always arrive not only unordered, but in a different -maybe random- order.

Is it possible to sort the attachments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like the attachments to be ordered as the ArrayList is

Then use exactly one attachment, where you attach a document that puts your images in the desired order.

Otherwise... your code is starting an `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` activity. There are likely thousands of these in the Play Store and elsewhere. How any of them handle your extras is up to their developers, not you or me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and help @CommonsWare. Your idea is good, but it has a little drawback. I could create -for example- a Word document as you say, but in the end I'll be subject to the user having Word or a Word viewer in its device installed. I think I'll mark your answer as correct and leave it as it is as you are right, there is no possibility to control this.

Comment: @DiegoPerez: "I could create -for example- a Word document as you say, but in the end I'll be subject to the user having Word or a Word viewer in its device installed" -- upload the images to your server, then create an HTML attachment that references the images. Or, try making an HTML attachment that uses `data` URLs for the images (not sure how practical that is). Or, make a PDF. Or, make a single image from all the other images, stitched together in your desired order. While a Word document is a possibility, it is not the only one.

Comment: Good set of possibilities I haven't thought of @CommonsWare. Thanks again for your help!